# Using #!python2 not working to run under Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have both Python 2 and 3 installed on my machine running Windows.

I am running a program via cmd which has the command `#!python2` at the very top of the code, and i want that to run in Python2.

It was my understanding that the having `#!python2` on the first line would force Python to use Python2. Instead it uses Python3 *[and hence the line 'print hello`results in the error`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to print` ]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story is a little more complicated on Windows than on Unix.

For Windows installations, when you install Python, the installer actually associates Python (.py) files with `py.exe`, an executable specifically made for launching Python on Windows.  You can read all about it in [PEP 397 -- Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

Since .py files are associated with that launcher, all the magic of reading the shebang line is implemented in `py.exe`.  Long story short, your first line must read

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

in order to work.  In [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), read the section titled "Python Script Launching" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the hash-bang requires a full path, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

If you've installed it such that there's an executable *somewhere* on your path called `python2`, you can find the full path to it by executing the command:

```
which python2
```

You'd then use the output of that command in the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

---

And of course, you can always run your script with whatever python version you want by specifying it explicitly:

```
python2 your_script.py
```

Run this way, the shebang will be completely ignored and `python2` will execute the script.